# kernel error on init (reference to shared library error)

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, embedded, buildroot

I'm trying to boot kernel on an stm32f469-disco board which is an ARM board with 16MB ram and 16MB flash storage. I've used buildroot to create my rootfs and kernel. after u-boot passes the control to the kernel, everything goes fine except the last part of it.

these are the last words that my kernel spoke before his death :)

```
   .
   .
   .
[    3.799978] Run /init as init process
[    3.895142] binfmt_flat: reference 0x1ec00 to shared library 152, killing mount!
SEGV
[    3.922521] binfmt_flat: reference 0x1ec00 to shared library 152, killing sh!
SEGV
[    3.945478] binfmt_flat: reference 0x1ec00 to shared library 152, killing init!
[    3.953585] Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b
[    3.961327] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x0000000b ]---
```

It seems a shared library is missing but why even it's using a shared library?

this is buildroot configuration

[image]